# RX How to subscribe only to specific events on a Subject

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observers, subject

I would like to know if it is possible using a Subject to only subscribe to specific type of events
For example I have an enum of ANIMAL

```
enum class ANIMAL {
    DOG, CAT, PARROT
}
```

Then I create a subject

```
val animalSubject: PublishSubject<ANIMAL> = PublishSubject.create()
```

but I want to Subscribe only to CATS how do it? This receives the events of all animals.

```
animalSubject.subscribe { println("I want only Cats here $it") }
```

I want to Subscribe only to Dog. I can use a filter here but it will receive all the events and filter only Dogs (not what I am looking for)

```
animalSubject.filter {it == ANIMAL.DOG}.subscribe { println("Only Dogs here $it") }
```

When I call onNext the event will be sent to all the observers. So I was thinking that there might be the possibility to get the observers from the subject and somehow check what kind of Animal the observers are subscribed to.

I am not sure if its possible using a Subject but what I am trying to avoid is to send ALL the events to all the observers. Maybe it would be good just to send the events to the ones subscribed to that specific Animal

Is this possible with a Subject or with other operator in RxJava?

Comment: What about creating 3 subjects, each for an animal type ? Or create 3 different methods (near the animalSubject which will be private) each filter on a type of animal

Comment: this is just a generic example, but I would like to extend it, say I have 1000 animals or the something specific to the animals.

Comment: In this case `filter` is your best friend. You can use `ofType` operator to filter on types.